# Binding list to get pushpins with Maps

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, bing-maps

Hello I'am using Bing maps in a WPF app,

My page contains a map.

The dataContext of my page contains a list of Place theses places have a GeoLocation :

```
public class GeoCoordinate
{
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public double altitude { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    [...]
    public GeoCoordinate position { get; set; }
}

public class datacontext
{
    [...]
    public List<Place> places { get; set; }

}
```

I would like to bind my list to make pushpins on my map for each place at its coordinate.
I tryed to use Map.Children property but without success...

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found it in the xaml I used MapItemsControl property:

```
<m:Map x:Name="myMap" CredentialsProvider="blabla" ZoomLevel="12" Mode="Road">
                <m:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding places}">
                    <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <m:Pushpin Location="{Binding position.location}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </m:MapItemsControl>                    
            </m:Map>
```

And I added the location property in GeoCoordinate class :

```
    public class GeoCoordinate
{
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public double altitude { get; set; }

    public Location location { get { return new Location(latitude, longitude, altitude); } }

}
```

Comment: I tried using your solution here, but I just get an Exception:
A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Latitude' property of type 'Location'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to check the get started section on MSDN so you can get the basics around the use of specific and dedicated classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830431.aspx

In order to add pushpin elements on your map control, you need to use `Pushpin` class, see:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.pushpin.aspx

And in use it's like this:

```
 // The pushpin to add to the map.
 Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
 pin.Location = pinLocation;

 // Adds the pushpin to the map.
 myMap.Children.Add(pin);
```

More information regarding how to get started with the pushpin here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh709044.aspx